# How can I have 2 meteor Version?

Tags: javascript, meteor, version

I have a project in meteor 1.2.1 and I was starting a new one in meteor 1.3.
When I tried to update my new meteor project to 1.3 the other one stop working as before.
I tried to downgrade with meteor update --release 1.2.1 but it didnt work as I expected.
How can I have two projects with different meteor versions? Anything special to do?
Anything wrong with this downgrade command?

Comment: I am able to run Meteor 1.2 and 1.3 projects in parallel on my mac without any problem. You may add your OS version and other information to your question, so that someone with similar setup can help you.

Answer (score 2):

**How can I have two projects with different meteor versions?**

Meteor maintains a list of previously installed versions on your computer so multiple apps on the same machine can use different versions (your exact use case). On *NIX operating systems, you can see the list with this:

```
ls ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/
```

**Anything wrong with this downgrade command?**

Probably. Meteor is designed to upgrade cleanly from version to version, but, as I understand it, downgrading may be another matter. My recommendation (assuming you are using version control) would be to check out whatever commit you made prior to the upgrade command.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that you don't downgrade you just run it with the --release flag and it runs as if that version were installed.

So install 1.3 and when you want to run as 1.2.1 use the release flag.

`> meteor --release 1.2.1`

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4526